# Light direction in Normal Map Bake

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

I'm new in blender and trying to bake normal from a high resolution mesh to a low poly.

But the result of the normal map is casting shadow from sky corresponding to some global illumination that I can't change.

[image]

As you can see in image some global light is casting shadow into normal result. I'm trying to put some lights in scene but whatever shadow direction I try the same result accurs.

How can I bake Normal without shadow direction? Like we do when we bake AO with light coming from all directions.

I hope you understand this ridiculous explanation. ;/

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal maps do not control the lighting of a surface, they only define surface facing direction. It is impossible to store light or shadow information in a normal map. You should not attempt to judge the information in a normal map based on what you see. It is not a shadow, these simply are numerical values that happen to be lower. You should look for the issue in your lighting or geometry if there are shadows where they should not be.

Comment: Thanks! Your tip give me the solution! :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the geometry. I just had to recalculate the faces normals so now everything is ok. Thank you @Martin Z for the tip!

[image]

[image]